# Is this a give-away audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I just reached 1000 on my low quality reviews. On review roughly 998, I received the following answer:

[image]

The number of votes cast, was, of course masked, but I mean the ID of the poster?

Was this some sort of congrats for 1000 audit, or just a coincidence?

Needless to say, I nailed it.

Comment: Congratulations!  That was a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention.  (Seriously though, that's all the audit does - makes sure that you're paying attention.)

Comment: Quite happy that last one was such a give away, it felt like a present for that final bump.

Comment: What is so magical about getting to 1000? I guess there's a badge or something? It's not like once you reach 1000 there are no more crappy posts to review. You can keep playing this game into the foreseeable future, don't fret!